# window function call requires an OVER clause

Tags: sql, postgresql

I have sql query that looks like this:

```
UPDATE people p
SET p.email = (SELECT 
                 MAX(FIRST_VALUE(email)) OVER (PARTITION BY person_id ORDER BY updated_at DESC)
               FROM person_emails pe
               WHERE pe.person_id = p.id);
```

it returns error:

```
 window function call requires an OVER clause
```

why?

Edit:

I've updated query to something like this:

```
UPDATE people p
  SET p.email = (
    SELECT MAX(
      FIRST_VALUE(email) OVER (PARTITION BY person_id ORDER BY updated_at DESC)
    )  
    FROM person_emails pe WHERE pe.person_id = p.id
  );
```

now it returns:

```
ERROR:  aggregate function calls cannot contain window function calls
LINE 4:       FIRST_VALUE(email) OVER (PARTITION BY person_id ORDER ...
              ^
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try:

```
UPDATE people p
  SET p.email = (
    SELECT MAX(first_email) 
    FROM (
     SELECT FIRST_VALUE(email) AS first_email, person_id OVER (PARTITION BY person_id ORDER BY updated_at DESC)
        FROM person_emails pe
    )  AS q
  WHERE q.person_id = p.id
  );
```

Comment: I've updated the query to something like this:

UPDATE people p
  SET p.email = (
    SELECT MAX(
      FIRST_VALUE(email) OVER (PARTITION BY person_id ORDER BY updated_at DESC)
    )  
    FROM person_emails pe WHERE pe.person_id = p.id
  );
now it returns:
ERROR:  aggregate function calls cannot contain window function calls
LINE 4:       FIRST_VALUE(email) OVER (PARTITION BY person_id ORDER ...

Comment: @MateuszUrbański Yes, that error sounds reasonable, I should have seen that. Corrected.